# Iterating through an array returns null when using getElementbyID

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to loop through a array of six numbers and modify a corresponding form element like so..

```
for(var x in numbers) { document.getElementById('r' + numbers[x]).value++; }
```

However this doesn't update the text field and the debugger says `Type Error: document.GetElementById(...) is null`. However the following code works as expected

```
var t = 25;
document.getElementById('r' + t).value++;
```

Can anyone shed any light on this? I'm not really a javascript programmer and am cobbling something together from code examples and I just can't see why the second case works but not the first.

ps. And yes I've tried with the more correct `for (var i=0; i < numbers.length; i++) {}` format ;)

Comment: Plz also provide your html and the content of `numbers`.

Comment: `for (.. in ..)` is **not** the same thing as `for (var i = ..)`.

Comment: A jsFiddle.net example would be useful.

Comment: Looks like your selector is wrong; but we have no way of knowing without the html and numbers array

Comment: `....value++;` ???? What is that supposed to do?

Comment: OK the HTML and full code is at http://jsbin.com/lukuyuxa/1/edit
I've tried the suggestions mentioned so far and none of them have worked for me so maybe its the numbers array (its actually called game[] now and is the function play2(). The function below it stats() was me passing the array and using it as numbers[]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this setup in jsbin is similar to what you have and it doesnt work...I'd suspect that your code is not finding the element in the DOM and you need to run the code when the DOM has actually loaded.

http://jsbin.com/fasibuse/1/edit?html,js,output

I think a more generic solution that would do the same thing ( increase the elements by 1 )...would be

```
var formElements = document.forms[0].getElementsByTagName( 'input' );

for (var el of formElements) {
  el.value++;
}
```

Comment: That jsbin setup was exactly what I'm looking for but it doesn't work in my script.  I've added my code at http://jsbin.com/lukuyuxa/1/edit

Comment: http://jsbin.com/virejeja/1/edit?js,output

Comment: Yes! Thankyou. So if I'm reading that right it seems the problem was my 6 numbers were the first element in an array of arrays. Doh!

Answer (score 0):

Read code directly:

```
var numbers = [10,20,30,40];
for(var x in numbers) {
    console.log(x); // <-- output 0,1,2,3 (the indexes, not the content)
}
```

You should use

```
numbers.forEach(function (x) {
    document.getElementById('r' + numbers[x]).value++;
});
```

Comment: ... as long as you don't need to support IE8, or are willing/able to use a polyfill to add `forEach`

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
    <input id="sparky1" value="1"><br>
    <input id="sparky2" value="3"><br>
    <input id="sparky3" value="5"><br>
    <input id="sparky4" value="7"><br>
    <input id="sparky5" value="9"><br>


    <script>
        for (var i=1; i < 6; i++) {
            document.getElementById('sparky' + i).value = parseInt(document.getElementById('sparky' + i).value) + 1;
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is invalid access of array element, here is correct one. try this one.

```
for(var x in numbers) { document.getElementById('r' + x).value++; }
```

this will work fine.